# Can I hide user folders from other Amazon S3 IAM users?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I'm creating a setup for users to upload files in an S3 bucket. Users will login via Cyberduck S3 for access to their buckets.

This is the basic way files are placed:

- bucket/user1/fileX
- bucket/user1/fileY
- bucket/user2/fileX
- bucket/user2/fileY

When a user is browsing to upload files I would like to prevent that they can see which other users have access to the bucket. 
User1 should not be able to see the user2 folder. Is this possible?

**Current policy:**

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::*"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        ""
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowListingOfUserFolder",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket"
            ],
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "StringLike": {
                    "s3:prefix": [
                        "${aws:username}/*"
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAllS3ActionsInUserFolder",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:*"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname/${aws:username}/*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case the best approach was to remove the acces to listing in the first statements:

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowUserToSeeBucketListInTheConsole",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListAllMyBuckets",
            "s3:GetBucketLocation"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        ]
    },
    {
        "Sid": "AllowRootAndHomeListingOfCompanyBucket",
        "Action": [
            "s3:ListBucket"
        ],
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:s3:::bucketname"
        ],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "s3:prefix": [
                    ""
                ]
            }
        }
    },
```

After this I have users login directly to their folder in Cyberduck. In order to access a folder directly create a bookmark instead of logging in directly. The bookmark options had more options to set.